# How to include frame with directions from Bing Maps into my web page?

Tags: bing-maps

I'd like that the results of Bing Maps get directions query were displayed on my web page. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot share directions from a to b doing this but you can have a map of a location with a link for users to generate their own directions to that location.

1) go to http://www.bing.com/maps/ and zoom and pan the map to the end point of your directions
2) click the share button on top right
3) Look at the 'embed' section for details